# Web Security not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, browser

I am currently using Web Security. User can log in using this code

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(loginRequest.EmailAddress, loginRequest.Password))
{
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginRequest.EmailAddress, false);
      var userDetails = new string[2];
      userDetails[0] = loginRequest.EmailAddress;
      var currentUSerRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(loginRequest.EmailAddress);
      userDetails[1] = currentUSerRole[0].ToString();
      return response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, userDetails);       
}
```

The login code works, but `IsAuthentcated` always returns false and `CurrentUsername` always return -1 and all `Websecurity methods` are not worked well when I run my application on Chrome and Firefox browsers. But it's working good on IE Browser.

What did I missed? Is it any cors issue? or anything else?  I found a lot of answers from Google, but they haven't helped me.

### Any One Help Me

Answer (score 0):

As per My knowledge

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(string, bool);` can be used to login/logout a particular user with the string a username and bool value as true/false for log in/out.

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("user", true);` will log in the user and the WebSecurity will have its userID.

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("admin", false);` will log out admin and will remove its userID from WebSecurity.

so you should try `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("user", true);`

Comment: hmm ! Not a answer for me. I tried this lot and lot of time. But not working